# How to copy from one blockquote to another blockquote?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is to transfer data value from ID one to ID two Data should be in the form of a submit button

javascript

```
<blockquote contenteditable="true" id = "1"><p></p> </blockquote>
```

```
<blockquote contenteditable="true" id = "2"><p></p> </blockquote>
```

```
<button type="Submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the innerHTML property for quick solution

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('sbmt');
let one = document.getElementById('1')
let two = document.getElementById('2')


btn.addEventListener('click', () =>
 {                  
  two.innerHTML= one.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
  
  <blockquote contenteditable="true" id = "1"><p> first box</p> </blockquote>
<blockquote contenteditable="true" id = "2"><p>second box</p> </blockquote>
<button type="Submit" id=sbmt>Submit</button>
```

Comment: mr can you ask me how to use "for loop" for id document.getElementById to copy multiple by one click submit button.

Comment: I will not answer it directly but can you read this link, hope this helps

https://itnext.io/5-ways-to-loop-over-dom-elements-from-queryselectorall-in-javascript-55bd66ca4128

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to transfer the content from the first blockquote with the id "1" to the second blockquote with the id "2" when the submit button is clicked.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blockquote Copy Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<blockquote contenteditable="true" id="1"><p></p></blockquote>
<blockquote contenteditable="true" id="2"><p></p></blockquote>
<button type="button" onclick="transferData()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function transferData() {
        // Get the content of the first blockquote
        var content1 = document.getElementById('1').innerText;

        // Set the content of the second blockquote
        document.getElementById('2').innerText = content1;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

transferData() method is triggered when submit button is clicked and this method retrieves the content from 1st id and transfers it to 2nd id.

Also replace the button type with "button" to prevent it from submitting a form, as we're handling the functionality with JavaScript.

Comment: did it work for you? I'm happy to help you. If the answer worked for you, please accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: yes, its worked if type on some word thanks

Comment: mr can you ask me how to use "for loop" for id document.getElementById to copy multiple by one click submit button.